# How to remove the duplicates in the expansion of $(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 \ldots+ a_n)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to remove the duplicates in the expansion of $(a_0 + a_1 + a_2 \ldots + a_n)^2$?

Is there a known formula or method to remove the duplicates from this expansion, for example, keep only one of $a_0\cdot a_1$ and $a_1\cdot a_0$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is exactly one of each $a_{i}^{2}$ term, and two of each $a_{i}a_{j}$ term (where $0 \le i <j$)

Answer (score 0):

General case: the [Multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one of $a_0 \cdot a_1$ or $a_1 \cdot a_0$, but not both;

the formula is just $\Sigma a_i^2+\Sigma_{i}\Sigma_{j=i+1}a_ia_j$

So for $(a+b+c)^2$ it would give $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac+bc$

Comment: Take $a = b = c = 1$. That would imply $3^2 = 6$.

Comment: I think your forgot factors $2$ in both the formula and the example.

Comment: I thought the question was to only have one of $a_0 \cdot a_1$ or $a_1 \cdot a_0$. If you only need one of them then surely you only have one lot of $ab, bc, ca$?